# Check if dropdown's selected option is not the first with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

Below are the options that I have in my HTML code:

```
    <label id="subn">
      <select name="subs" id="subs">
        <option value="nothing">Choose a Subject</option>
        <option value="General Question">General Question</option>
        <option value="MemberShip Area">MemberShip Area</option>
        <option value="Others">Others</option>
      </select>
    </label>
```

I want to create JavaScript code that will check whether the user selected an option other than the first one.

Here is what I tried:

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName('option') == "nothing"){
    document.getElementById("subn").innerHTML = "Subject is Required!";
    document.getElementById("subs").focus();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can check like this if `nothing` is the first option (usually the case in my experience):

```
if (document.getElementById('subs').selectedIndex == 0){
```

To still compare based on the value, do this:

```
var sel = document.getElementById('subs');
if (sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value == 'nothing') {
```

You may want to change your markup so the label is beside, like this:

```
<select name="subs" id="subs"></select><label id="subn" for="subs"></label>
```

Otherwise this part: `.innerHTML = "Subject is Required!";` will erase your `<select>` :)

Comment: You have written `document.getElementsByTagName('subs')` where you mean `document.getElementById('subs')`

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
var index = document.your_form_name.subs.selectedIndex;
var value = document.your_form_name.subs.options[index].value;

if (value === "nothing"){
   // your further code here.........
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName('option')` gives a collection of all `option` elements in the document and `"nothing"` is a string. Comparing a collection to a string is quite useless.

Also setting `document.getElementById("subn").innerHTML = "Subject is Required!";` will delete the `select` element, so `document.getElementById("subs")` wouldn't find anything any more.

If you just need to know if anything is selected check the `selectedIndex` property of the `select` element:

```
if (document.getElementById("subs").selectedIndex <= 0) {
  // nothing is selected
}
```

*EDIT:* Changed `> 0` to `<= 0`. I would assume that it should be checked if the user didn't select anything, too.

Comment: Your `if()` is backwards, if it's `> 0` nothing is **not** selected, he wants the reverse check.

Comment: Well, in the text he wrote "if the user select a subject other than the first", but in in his example he tried to check if the first was selected, so there is a bit of a contradiction.

Comment: He's adding a message *if they selected nothing*, it's backwards.  This is **very** clear from his code, I'm not sure where the confusion is...